# Jquery not reading from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Ok, so here is the code for my HTML:

```
<div id="contentholder">
    <div class="personcard">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        <h2>Matej Vydra <span>Striker</span></h2>
        <p>This is a paragraph about Watford Striker Matej Vydra, it doesnt really make much sense, but its great for testing and lolz.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the JS and JSON files:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('json/currentsquad.json', function (currentsquad) {
        var output = "<div class='personcard'>";
        for (var i in currentsquad.players) {
            output += "<img src='" + currentsquad.players[i].image + "'/> <h2>" + currentsquad.players[i].name + "<span>" + currentsquad.players[i].position + "</span> </h2>";
        }
        output += "</div>";
        document.getElementById("contentholder").innerHTML = output;
    });
});
```

json:

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "image": "http://placehold.it/400x400",
            "name": "Matej Vydra",
            "position": "Striker"
        },
        {
            "image": "http://placehold.it/400x400",
            "name": "Troy Deeney",
            "position": "Striker"
        },
]
}
```

And the problem is that the code is not getting shown to the user, I have tried searching previously and therefore tried running it on localhost but the issue stays the same and the JSON isn't shown to the user.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the last comma after the `},` in the data in `currentsquad.json` file.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/QsHw4/light/

Comment: check Felipe's answer  your json was invalid json ..

Comment: How are you getting that extra comma in the first place. No decent JSON generator would create it. Are you trying to build it yourself? Is the trailing comma actually there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid. While the JavaScript object literal notation allows for a trailing comma, the JSON standard does not. So if this is an accurate representation of the JSON you're sending, you'll need to remove the comma after the last object in the `players` Array.

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "image": "http://placehold.it/400x400",
            "name": "Matej Vydra",
            "position": "Striker"
        },
        {
            "image": "http://placehold.it/400x400",
            "name": "Troy Deeney",
            "position": "Striker"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Give a half-way decent explanation of exactly what you changed and why, and I'll remove the vote. It's technically correct but very low quality.

Comment: well you dont need to downvote for that, you could just ask

Comment: @FelipeSkinner: Why wouldn't I? Votes are for rating the quality of the answer. Give better answers, you'll get better voting feedback.

Comment: I guess -1 is for when a answer is both wrong and bad but oh well... btw your answer will give in another invalid json since json does not accept comments

Comment: i removed it since its not a big change and he can compare with the previous one to find out whats changed. besides you've already gave a good explanation

Comment: Fair point about the comment, though I very seriously doubt that the OP would be dumb enough to actually include the comment in the rendered JSON.

Comment: hehehe i don't know but there are lots of beginners around that might not know that... just want to be sure :)